# Using dictionaries stored in another jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

Please be kind to me, I am new to python.

I have thousands of dictionaries saved in one jupyter notebook (controlled by IT team), and I would like to utilize some of the dictionaries in those into my jupyter notebook. Is there a way I can achieve this.

Example: IT team-Jupyter notebook contains one of the below dictionary (just a sample):

```
dict_sample={'HR':'Human Resource','FIN':'Finance','LG':'Legal'}
```

I would like to utilize the above dictionary of IT-Team into my jupyter notebook. Dummy df created below for reference.

```
data = {'name': ['John', 'Aaron', 'Anie'], 
    'Dept': ['HR', 'FIN', 'LG']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name','Dept'])

df["Dept"]=df["Dept"].map(dict_sample)
```

Comment: I think your solution working nice, what is question ?

Comment: Hi, I want to import or use dictionaries saved in another jupyter notebook, how can I do that.
Example: above dictionary saved in jupyter notebook1, how do I use the dictionary of jupyter notebook 1 to jupyter notebook 2.

Comment: do you have access to df1? could you save the dicts there to disk via pickle or json?

Comment: i can get access to it.

Comment: i followed this website; i find it useful using pickle, thanks Ezer
https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/#:~:text=First%2C%20import%20pickle%20to%20use,into%20opened%20file%2C%20then%20close.&text=Use%20pickle.,-load()%20to